# function returns the value of a pointer without "return" statement

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I wanted to attach two linked lists using `concat()` function,
but I have noticed that `concat()` returns the last value of `head` although there is no `return` at the end of `concat()`!

what I mean is when I send the heads of the following two linked lists to `concat()` : `1->2->3->4` and `5->6->7`

I do expect an ouput like this :`1->2->3->4->5->6->7` ,but instead I get a linked list of this form `4->5->6->7`!

can I know where's the problem? thanks in advance

```
typedef struct node{
int data;
struct node* next;
}list;
```

```
list* Concat(list* head,list* P)
{
    if(!head)   return  P;
    if(!P)  return head;
    while(head->next)   head=head->next;
    head->next=P;
}
```

Comment: `can I know where's the problem?` The problem is `there is no return at the end of concat()`

Comment: If the function ends without executing a `return` statement it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Your code is invalid. A function with a signature other than `void ...` without `return` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Undefined behaviour. If it works, the value happened to be in the right place to be found accidentally.

Comment: What actually gets returned is unspecified, although in many implementations it will end up being the value of the last statement that was executed because it happens to use the same register used for return values.

Comment: Didn't you get any compiler warnings? Compile with `-Wall`.